# in Rails, database call works in development but stalls in test

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am running a test for a controller method as shown below:

```
it "should assigns an instance var @items including my item" do
  @item = FactoryGirl.create(:item)
  get :index
  response.should include(@item)
end
```

The controller method is:

```
def index
  @Item = Item.select_items
end
```

where select_items is a scope method in the Items model:

```
scope :select_items, where(Items.arel_table[:select_field].not_eq(nil))
```

In development, this works fine.  In test however, I get

- A 500 error when I test the controller method itself in the console
- No error when I simply test the model method in the console
- A permanent hang when I run the spec

In test.log, the hang happens at the last line of the following:

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
  Admin Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `admins`.* FROM `admins` 
   (0.6ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO `items` (`various fields')
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Processing by Admin::ItemsController#index as HTML
  Admin Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `admins`.* FROM `admins` WHERE `admins`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  Rendered admin/items/index.haml within layouts/tabs (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 15ms (Views: 3.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
  Item Load (1.2ms)  SELECT `items`.* FROM `items` WHERE (`item`.`select_field` IS NOT NULL) LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

If I run the test in rspec, the spec stops at this point.  Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test should be like this:

```
it "should assigns an instance var @items including my item" do
  @item = FactoryGirl.create(:item)
  get :index
  assigns(:Item).should include(@item)
end
```

Your controller assigned an instance variable, and that is how you access them. The `response` holds a lot of information you probably never need to look at in your test. The exception is if you are returning things like JSON or XML, in which case you'd look at `response.body`.

In addition, considering your controller instance variable is grabbing possible *multiple* items, you should name your variable `@Items`, pluralized. Furthermore, you never capitalize instance variables, so it should be `@items`. And lastly for nitpicky things, in your test, you don't need to make `@item` an instance variable as it exists just for your single `it`.

Comment: This is partially correct.  The syntax necessary was actually `assigns(:item).should include(@item)`.  `assigns` takes symbols or strings, not variable names themselves.  Thanks for getting me this far though

Comment: Oh my mistake on that! I knew that too, but somehow missed that. Thanks for pointing that out! I will adjust my answer now for future visitors!